# How can I create daily partitions in Postgres using Flyway

Tags: postgresql, flyway

The [Flyway FAQ says](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq#outside-changes) I can't make structural changes to the DB outside of Flyway. Does that includes creating new partitions for an existing table? 
If so, is there any way to use Flyway to automatically create daily partitions as required? Bear in mind that the process will be running for more than one day so it's not something that can be just triggered on start-up.
We're stuck with Postgres 9.6 at the mo, so the partitions have to be created manually.

Comment: Are you actually deploying your schema migrations **every day**?

Comment: A better way would be to use [pg_partnam](https://pgxn.org/dist/pg_partman/) and let it run `run_maintenance()` in regular intervals.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name we just need to create partitions for each day. We could create N at a time rather than daily, but we want to be able to create them without having to restart the system. Thanks for the reference to pg_partnam, wasn't aware of it. The question is, does Flyway consider the creation of a partition, by whatever means, to be a structural change to the database?